# Derivative of a cumulatively increasing piece-wise constant function. Does my attempt make sense?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, piecewise-continuity, step-function

In this [paper](https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/opre.23.2.260) a few steps are missing. I am trying to fill in the gaps to gain understanding. The following integral is given

$$
\int_{0}^\infty e^{-\beta t}\,dD_k(t)
$$
where we have a interest rate $\beta \geq 0$ and a departure process $D_k(t)$. This function is piece-wise constant over intervals $[t_{k-1},t_k)$ at some integer value. In the next interval $[t_k,t_{k+1}]$ it then increases by one over the previous values. In other words
$$
D_{k+1} = D_k(t) + 1, \quad t \in [t_k,t_{k+1})
$$
I would like to compute the above integral but need to deal with $dD_k(t)$. I do so by reasoning with the [Heaveside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) $H_a(t)$ where $a$ is the point at which the step occurs. Let us assume $D_0(0) = 0$ such that
$$
D_k(t) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} H_{t_k}(t) \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{t_k \leq t\}}
$$
where the inidcator function is simply there as a constraint that will be omitted soon. The derivative of $H_{a}(t)$ is the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) $\delta_a(t)$. Then we have
$$
\frac{dD_k}{dt} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \delta_{t_k}(t)\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{t_k \leq t\}}
$$
such that the integral becomes the following.
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{0}^\infty e^{-\beta t}\,dD_k(t)  &=&  \int_{0}^\infty  e^{-\beta t} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \delta_{t_k}(t)\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{t_k \leq t\}} \right) \, dt\\
 &=& \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-\beta t_k}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
The above answer seems to be what the original paper obtained. I am just not quite sure if this is how one would go about getting the solution. I am afraid that I have "forced" a solution.

Please do point out whether this is nonsense, where I have gone wrong and how it it should be improved upon.

Comment: Seems right to me

Comment: If one looks a little more closely at the definition of the Stieljes integral (which is the version of integration that allows such differentials of functions), it is not necessary to resort to psuedo-functions like the Dirac delta to derive this. But the result is the same.